# Observer global variables reactjs

Tags: reactjs, mobx, mobx-react

Is it possible to observer global const for example gloabl const we can call this Auth.ts

I would like to do this https://mobx-react.js.org/observe-how but globaly

```
import { observable, action, computed } from 'mobx';

const userAutehnticationObserver = observable({
  loggedIn: false,
  tokenId: ''
})
```

and from another tsx function

```
import React from "react";

    const Dashboard = () => {
    const P1 = observer(function P1({ userAutehnticationObserver }) {
      return <h1>{person.name}</h1>
    })
      return (
        <div>
        </div>
      );
    };
    export default Dashboard;
```

and third function change something onClick to first global const which is observable by this second function

Comment: Did you mean something like High Order Component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course, you can do that basically you inject the store in the different components that you need, that in the case that you need to change something can use an action to produce a change in the global store. That will be reflected in all the component that has injected the store and use the observer

Comment: Maybe for more details, you could check this https://mobx.js.org/README.html

Sections:
Egghead.io lesson 3: computed values and 
Egghead.io lesson 1: observable & observer